# Cannot reinstall OpenManage 7.4 packages, claims dependencies are uninstallable

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, dell-poweredge, drac

### How the issue began

Recently, whilst upgrading, OpenManage attempted to upgrade to version 8.3.0 and failed due to unmet dependencies with the message `srvadmin-isvc : Depends: srvadmin-hapi (>= 8.3.0) but 7.4.0-1 is installed`. This is not the wanted behavior, as I want to stay on version 7.4 for support for older hardware.

---

### Attempted solution

First, I uninstalled OpenManage using the command `sudo dpkg --force-all --force-depends -P srvadmin-all`. I then limited the repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linux.dell.com.sources.list` to version 7.4 using `deb http://linux.dell.com/repo/community/ubuntu trusty openmanage/740`. I ran `sudo apt-get update`, and here's where the trouble started.

---

### The problem

`sudo apt-get install srvadmin-all` failed with the following:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 srvadmin-all : Depends: srvadmin-base (>= 7.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: srvadmin-storageservices (>= 7.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: srvadmin-webserver (>= 7.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: srvadmin-rac4 (>= 7.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: srvadmin-rac5 (>= 7.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: srvadmin-idrac (>= 7.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: srvadmin-idrac7 (>= 7.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: srvadmin-server-snmp (>= 7.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: srvadmin-server-cli (>= 7.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: srvadmin-oslog (>= 7.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`sudo aptitude install srvadmin-all` ran (but didn't solve the issue) with more information:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  srvadmin-all srvadmin-base{a} srvadmin-deng{a} srvadmin-deng-snmp{a} srvadmin-hapi{ab} srvadmin-idrac{ab} srvadmin-idrac-ivmcli{a} srvadmin-idrac-snmp{a} srvadmin-idrac-vmcli{a} srvadmin-idrac7{ab} srvadmin-idracadm{ab} srvadmin-idracadm7{ab} srvadmin-isvc{ab} 
  srvadmin-isvc-snmp{a} srvadmin-jre{ab} srvadmin-nvme{a} srvadmin-omacore{ab} srvadmin-omacs{a} srvadmin-omcommon{ab} srvadmin-omilcore{ab} srvadmin-ominst{a} srvadmin-oslog{a} srvadmin-rac-components{a} srvadmin-rac4{a} srvadmin-rac4-populator{a} srvadmin-rac5{a} 
  srvadmin-racadm4{a} srvadmin-racadm5{ab} srvadmin-racdrsc{a} srvadmin-racsvc{ab} srvadmin-realssd{a} srvadmin-rnasoap{a} srvadmin-server-cli{a} srvadmin-server-snmp{a} srvadmin-smcommon{a} srvadmin-smweb{a} srvadmin-standardagent{a} srvadmin-storage{ab} 
  srvadmin-storage-cli{a} srvadmin-storage-snmp{a} srvadmin-storageservices{a} srvadmin-storageservices-cli{a} srvadmin-storageservices-snmp{a} srvadmin-storelib{a} srvadmin-storelib-sysfs{ab} srvadmin-tomcat{a} srvadmin-webserver{a} srvadmin-xmlsup{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 48 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 35.1 MB of archives. After unpacking 101 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 srvadmin-omacore : Depends: smbios-utils but it is not installable.
 srvadmin-omcommon : Depends: libsmbios2 but it is not installable.
                     Depends: smbios-utils but it is not installable.
 srvadmin-racadm5 : Depends: libargtable2-0 (>= 7) but it is not installable.
 srvadmin-storelib-sysfs : PreDepends: libsysfs2 but it is not installable.
 srvadmin-idracadm : Depends: libargtable2-0 (>= 7) but it is not installable.
 srvadmin-idracadm7 : Depends: libargtable2-0 (>= 7) but it is not installable.
 srvadmin-hapi : Depends: smbios-utils but it is not installable.
 srvadmin-idrac7 : Depends: libargtable2-0 but it is not installable.
 srvadmin-jre : Depends: icedtea-netx which is a virtual package.
 srvadmin-racsvc : Depends: setserial but it is not installable.
 srvadmin-isvc : Depends: smbios-utils but it is not installable.
 srvadmin-omilcore : Depends: smbios-utils but it is not installable.
 srvadmin-idrac : Depends: libargtable2-0 but it is not installable.
 srvadmin-storage : Depends: libsmbios2 but it is not installable.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)      srvadmin-all [Not Installed]                       
2)      srvadmin-base [Not Installed]                      
3)      srvadmin-deng [Not Installed]                      
4)      srvadmin-deng-snmp [Not Installed]                 
5)      srvadmin-hapi [Not Installed]                      
6)      srvadmin-idrac [Not Installed]                     
7)      srvadmin-idrac-ivmcli [Not Installed]              
8)      srvadmin-idrac-snmp [Not Installed]                
9)      srvadmin-idrac7 [Not Installed]                    
10)     srvadmin-idracadm [Not Installed]                  
11)     srvadmin-idracadm7 [Not Installed]                 
12)     srvadmin-isvc [Not Installed]                      
13)     srvadmin-isvc-snmp [Not Installed]                 
14)     srvadmin-jre [Not Installed]                       
15)     srvadmin-nvme [Not Installed]                      
16)     srvadmin-omacore [Not Installed]                   
17)     srvadmin-omacs [Not Installed]                     
18)     srvadmin-omcommon [Not Installed]                  
19)     srvadmin-omilcore [Not Installed]                  
20)     srvadmin-ominst [Not Installed]                    
21)     srvadmin-oslog [Not Installed]                     
22)     srvadmin-rac4 [Not Installed]                      
23)     srvadmin-rac4-populator [Not Installed]            
24)     srvadmin-rac5 [Not Installed]                      
25)     srvadmin-racadm5 [Not Installed]                   
26)     srvadmin-racdrsc [Not Installed]                   
27)     srvadmin-racsvc [Not Installed]                    
28)     srvadmin-realssd [Not Installed]                   
29)     srvadmin-rnasoap [Not Installed]                   
30)     srvadmin-server-cli [Not Installed]                
31)     srvadmin-server-snmp [Not Installed]               
32)     srvadmin-smweb [Not Installed]                     
33)     srvadmin-storage [Not Installed]                   
34)     srvadmin-storage-cli [Not Installed]               
35)     srvadmin-storage-snmp [Not Installed]              
36)     srvadmin-storageservices [Not Installed]           
37)     srvadmin-storageservices-cli [Not Installed]       
38)     srvadmin-storageservices-snmp [Not Installed]      
39)     srvadmin-storelib [Not Installed]                  
40)     srvadmin-storelib-sysfs [Not Installed]            
41)     srvadmin-tomcat [Not Installed]                    
42)     srvadmin-webserver [Not Installed]
```

I'm hoping that Dell hasn't pulled down the repositories and it's on my end.

---

### My setup

Dell PowerEdge 2850 with DRAC 4/I installed running Ubuntu Server 14.04. Unfortunately, while I do have backups, they're only of my home folder.

---

### Additional info

Per request, the output of `apt-cache show srvadmin-all`.

```
Package: srvadmin-all
Priority: optional
Section: partner/utils
Installed-Size: 25
Maintainer: Daniel Jared Dominguez <Jared_Dominguez@Dell.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: srvadmin-meta
Version: 7.4.0
Depends: srvadmin-base (>= 7.4.0), srvadmin-storageservices (>= 7.4.0), srvadmin-webserver (>= 7.4.0), srvadmin-standardagent (>= 7.4.0), srvadmin-rac4 (>= 7.4.0), srvadmin-rac5 (>= 7.4.0), srvadmin-idrac (>= 7.4.0), srvadmin-idrac7 (>= 7.4.0), srvadmin-server-snmp (>= 7.4.0), srvadmin-server-cli (>= 7.4.0), srvadmin-oslog (>= 7.4.0)
Filename: pool/trusty/openmanage/740/OMSA/amd64/srvadmin-all_7.4.0_amd64.deb
Size: 1880
MD5sum: d1ad8e97c1faf41c7dae4ae21554770f
SHA1: 31984c10407e9b3864a755317fab1eeb944cabb0
SHA256: 1294920ae84673d860b07e71b1b900e12b26cbafa8485cb2a2984b80b67f3a39
SHA512: 1471807dc6366f714900ec95512b7383e0c51af26829c4ab71a2273627de00e03239ff81e181be3130586e2375530801c2a1b2dc163819f013f66652bfbe799d
Description: Meta package for installing all Server Administrator features
 Meta-package that contains dependency information to automatically pull
 in all base and optional Server Administrator Features.
Description-md5: 7d7cc7ea41588bb1b03f2a5da6d51a9a
Homepage: http://support.dell.com
```

Both `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` appear to be empty.

Comment: Please post the output of `apt-cache show srvadmin-all`

Comment: @DWORDPTR Done.

Comment: Maybe this note in this page http://linux.dell.com/repo/community/ubuntu/ should be considered :

    Upgrade

    To upgrade to OMSA v8.3, it is *highly* recommended that you first remove the old installation first.

Comment: @sfk I'm not upgrading to v8.3, and I did remove the old installation.

Comment: it seems that core libraries are not installable (like libsmbios2). Could you please check that standard ubuntu packages are still available from your sources.list or sources.list.d ?

Comment: @sfk They both appear to be empty, how odd... `sudo apt-get update` seems to work as normal though. Added more info in the body

Comment: you should have the deb source for the ubuntu dstrib itself. Like `deb http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main `

Comment: @sfk Thanks, I [used a tool to regenerate the necessary sources](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php) and now it works. Feel free to add your answer as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that core libraries are not installable (like libsmbios2).

You should have the deb source for the ubuntu dstrib itself somewhere in your sources.list of sources.list.d

```
deb http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
```